# How to integrate swagger information submission into automated user interface testing using Katalon Studio?

Tags: api, testing, automated-tests, swagger, katalon-studio

Good evening people,

I would like to create Katalon interface tests on a system under development, but I am having difficulty. The system involves an icon of a car that needs to travel through a stream, but to get it out of some processes (such as arrival, middle, and end), it receives Swagger parameters that simulate or PLC bus, like closing a gate to let the car out, for example.
Can I create an automated test that sends this information from swagger by importing Swagger's JSON in Katalon? Is there any other example besides PetStore?

Thanks